# Python Cyrillic encoding output

Tags: python, encoding, output

I just started learning python, and I am doing exercises for dictionaries, but since the sample code I have to use is in Cyrillic, I'm having some encoding issues. I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

temperatures = {
    'София': -14,
    'Новосибирск': -31
}

print("-" * 20)
print(temperatures)

print("-" * 20)

key = 'Бургас'
if key in temperatures:
    print(temperatures[key])
else:
    print("No data for {}".format(key))
```

Before adding the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` line I was getting SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0'. Now however, the error is gone but the output of the words in Cyrillic is not right. This is the output:

```
--------------------
{'\xd0\x9d\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80\xd1\x81\xd0\xba': -31, '\xd0\xa1\xd0\xbe\xd1\x84\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f': -14}
--------------------
No data for Бургас
```

So, the words in Cyrillic which are printed out from the python dict are messed up, but the line `Бургас` appears right. I tried using `print(format(temperatures))` but the output is the same. If it prints out one Cyrillic word, shouldn't it print all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, can't comment yet: Your code works for me (emacs on arch linux).

edit: My default python interpreter is Python3.6, it get the same output as you with Python2.7. Is Python 2.7 a requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use a Python 2, the output here is *as expected*:

- when you print a string, it is printed directly
- when you print a dictionnary, the keys (and values) as printed using `repr` and not `str`. That explains why all characters having code points above 255 use their escaped form.

If you want to display a dictionnary in Python 2, you must do it *by hand*:

```
h = temperatures
print('{' + ', '.join((str(k)+ ': ' + str(h[k]) for k in h.keys())) + '}')
```